# CS:GO Dust 2 smokes

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

Is there any way to smoke the x box (mid) from T Spawn? I know that you can smoke it from the lower tunnels, but can you do it any other way?

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is!
I believe you want to do something like the [this.](http://puu.sh/cK5y0/0c4668f166.webm)

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdrXX.jpg) is a bit further information in regards to this smoke!

I hope that helps out!

Comment: In addition to this you can check out [this community map](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=447269341) for other smokes on Dust 2